# UI5 table binding with navigation property

Tags: sapui5

I have a odata model that I want to bind to my table in my XML-view.
The thing is, my data consists of objects, and these objects have 1 property that is an array.
This array is what i want to show in my table.

I can't make it work, maybe because something like "ToWorkingDays/Data" isn't working with the table binding?
Maybe you can help me.
The metadata should be right.

My data:
First the location and then the "ToWorkingDays" Data:

```
[{
    "LocationID": 0,
    "Title": "blabla",
    "Subtitle": "subtitle",
    "RandomNumber": "123"
}]

[{ "LocationID": 0,
"WorkingDaysID": 0,
"Data": [{
    "Weekday": "Mon",
    "WorkingTimeStart": "08:00",
    "WorkingTimeEnd": "18:00",
    "PauseTimeStart": "12:00",
    "PauseTimeEnd": "13:00"
}, {
    "Weekday": "Tue",
    "WorkingTimeStart": "08:00",
    "WorkingTimeEnd": "18:00",
    "PauseTimeStart": "12:00",
    "PauseTimeEnd": "13:00"
}] }]
```

My XML-view:

```
<Table items="{ToWorkingDays/Data}">
        <columns>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Weekday"/>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Work Time"/>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Pause Time"/>
            </Column>
            <Column hAlign="End"/>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <ObjectIdentifier title="{Weekday}"/>
                    <Text text="{parts: [{path: 'WorkingTimeStart'}, {path: 'WorkingTimeEnd'}], formatter: '.getSpanValue'}"/>
                    <Text visible="{=${PauseTimeStart} !== undefined}"
                        text="{parts: [{path: 'jsonModel>PauseTimeStart'}, {path: 'PauseTimeEnd'}], formatter: '.getSpanValue'}"/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://edit" press="onEditPress"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
```

My binding:

```
this.getView().bindElement({
            parameters: {
                expand: "ToWorkingDays"
            },
            path: "/" + sPath
        });
```

My error:

List Binding is not bound against a list for /ToWorkinDays/Data

Comment: Is your model the default unnamed model? What is "ToWorkingDays"?

Comment: yes it is! and ToWorkingDays is the navigation property to my working days

Comment: Did you try "/ToWorkingDays/Data"? Is your view bound to a single element?

Comment: yes i tried. <Table items="{/ToWorkingDays/Data}">

Comment: my view is bound to the data and it shows itself accordingly if i visit the ui5 controls.

Comment: If your view is already bound to `/ToWorkingDays` (meaning sPath in your `bindElement` is `ToWorkingDays`), you can just use `/Days` in your items binding of the Table

Comment: @Nitin /Data not /Days :)

Comment: @Cmdd Yeah, sorry! My bad! But did it work? you may not need the preceding `/` as well (`items="Data"`)

Comment: I'm wondering the same :D Is @sleepysimon that should answer! By the way: how is your sPath string?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should be like this:
 `items="{modelname>/Customers}`" and 
 `<Text text="{modelname>Name"}/>`.

```
{"Customers":[{
    "ID":1, 
    "Name": "TestCustomer"
}..]}
```